# Assembling multiple tables of deltas into a single populate view (i.e. No NULL)?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Lets say I have 2 (or more) tables containing lists of value changes for various variables. Both tables have the same structure. We can assume that each variable has an entry at the first TimeStamp. TimeStamps may be repeated if more than one variable changed with that record.

```
TableA                          TableB
____________________        _____________________
|Time    |ID |Value|        |Time    |ID  |Value|
|1:00    |Foo|    0|        |1:00    |Foo2|0.000|
|1:00    |Bar|   10|        |1:00    |Bar2|0.000| 
|1:00    |Baz|  100|        |1:00    |Baz2|0.000| 
|1:05    |Foo|    1|        |1:06    |Foo2|0.001|
|1:10    |Bar|   11|        |1:11    |Bar2|0.010| 
|1:15    |Baz|  101|        |1:16    |Baz2|0.100| 
|1:15    |Foo|    2|        |1:16    |Foo2|0.002|
|1:20    |Bar|   12|        |1:21    |Bar2|0.020| 
|1:25    |Baz|  102|        |1:26    |Baz2|0.200| 
|1:30    |Foo|    3|        |1:31    |Foo2|0.003|
|1:35    |Bar|   13|        |1:36    |Bar2|0.030| 
|1:35    |Baz|  103|        |1:36    |Baz2|0.300|
```

How would I select certain columns from these tables to assemble the records into a single view where the value of each column is assumed to be the last known value for that variable? For example to produce on of the two following results.

```
_________________________________________________________________________
|Time    |Foo.Value|Bar.Value|Baz.Value|Foo2.Value|Bar2.Value|Baz2.Value| 
|1:00    |        0|       10|      100|     0.000|     0.000|     0.000|
|1:05    |        1|       10|      100|     0.000|     0.000|     0.000|
|1:06    |        1|       10|      100|     0.001|     0.000|     0.000|
|1:10    |        1|       11|      100|     0.001|     0.000|     0.000|
|1:11    |        1|       11|      100|     0.001|     0.010|     0.000|
|1:15    |        2|       11|      101|     0.001|     0.010|     0.000|
|1:16    |        2|       11|      101|     0.002|     0.010|     0.100|
|1:20    |        2|       12|      101|     0.002|     0.010|     0.100|
|1:21    |        2|       12|      101|     0.002|     0.020|     0.100|
|1:25    |        2|       12|      102|     0.002|     0.020|     0.100|
|1:26    |        2|       12|      102|     0.002|     0.020|     0.200|
|1:30    |        3|       12|      102|     0.002|     0.020|     0.200|
|1:31    |        3|       12|      102|     0.003|     0.020|     0.200|
|1:35    |        3|       13|      103|     0.003|     0.020|     0.200|
|1:36    |        3|       13|      103|     0.003|     0.030|     0.300|

________________________________________________
|Time|Foo.Value|Bar.Value|Bar2.Value|Baz2.Value|
|1:00|        0|       10|     0.000|     0.000|
|1:05|        1|       10|     0.000|     0.000|
|1:10|        1|       11|     0.000|     0.000|
|1:11|        1|       11|     0.010|     0.000|
|1:15|        2|       11|     0.010|     0.000|
|1:16|        2|       11|     0.010|     0.100|
|1:20|        2|       12|     0.010|     0.100|
|1:25|        2|       12|     0.020|     0.100|
|1:26|        2|       12|     0.020|     0.200|
|1:31|        3|       12|     0.020|     0.200|
|1:35|        3|       13|     0.020|     0.200|
|1:36|        3|       13|     0.030|     0.300|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to combine all the rows to get the `Time` you want in the result set.

```
select A.Time
from dbo.TableA as A
where A.ID in ('Foo', 'Bar')
union
select B.Time
from dbo.TableB as B
where B.ID in ('Bar2', 'Baz2');
```

Using `union` instead of `union all` will remove duplicate `Time` values.

For each value you want to get you can use a subquery correlated on `Time` against the query above that does a `top(1)` ordered by `Time` descending.

```
select top(1) A.Value from dbo.TableA as A
where A.Time <= T.Time and A.ID = 'Foo'
order by A.Time desc;
```

Combining the query to get the `Time` values with all the columns you want to get your second result would look like this:

```
select T.Time,
       (select top(1) A.Value from dbo.TableA as A
        where A.Time <= T.Time and A.ID = 'Foo'
        order by A.Time desc) as [Foo.Value],
       (select top(1) A.Value from dbo.TableA as A
        where A.Time <= T.Time and A.ID = 'Bar'
        order by A.Time desc) as [Bar.Value],
       (select top(1) B.Value from dbo.TableB as B
        where B.Time <= T.Time and B.ID = 'Bar2'
        order by B.Time desc) as [Bar2.Value],
       (select top(1) B.Value from dbo.TableB as B
        where B.Time <= T.Time and B.ID = 'Bar2'
        order by B.Time desc) as [Bar2.Value]
from (
     select A.Time
     from dbo.TableA as A
     where A.ID in ('Foo', 'Bar')
     union
     select B.Time
     from dbo.TableB as B
     where B.ID in ('Bar2', 'Baz2')
     ) as T
order by T.Time;
```

And adding the columns to get the first result you get this:

```
select T.Time,
       (select top(1) A.Value from dbo.TableA as A
        where A.Time <= T.Time and A.ID = 'Foo'
        order by A.Time desc) as [Foo.Value],
       (select top(1) A.Value from dbo.TableA as A
        where A.Time <= T.Time and A.ID = 'Bar'
        order by A.Time desc) as [Bar.Value],
       (select top(1) A.Value from dbo.TableA as A
        where A.Time <= T.Time and A.ID = 'Baz'
        order by A.Time desc) as [Baz.Value],
       (select top(1) B.Value from dbo.TableB as B
        where B.Time <= T.Time and B.ID = 'Foo2'
        order by B.Time desc) as [Foo2.Value],
       (select top(1) B.Value from dbo.TableB as B
        where B.Time <= T.Time and B.ID = 'Bar2'
        order by B.Time desc) as [Bar2.Value],
       (select top(1) B.Value from dbo.TableB as B
        where B.Time <= T.Time and B.ID = 'Baz2'
        order by B.Time desc) as [Baz2.Value]
from (
     select A.Time
     from dbo.TableA as A
     where A.ID in ('Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz')
     union
     select B.Time
     from dbo.TableB as B
     where B.ID in ('Foo2', 'Bar2', 'Baz2')
     ) as T
order by T.Time;
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks you.

And thank you for explaining what is going on, it's nice to know what the hell is happening in addition to having it happen.